# React Native : Undefined is not object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native

I Use Custom Drawer on React Native. and I Have 3 Bottom Tab Navigator. Chat, Home and Profile Tab. And then on Home I create some of box, if box clicked, it would be navigate to another view.
[image: home menu]

this is MenuHome Component that i called when the Home Navigation Pressed.

```
const MenuHome = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.box}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CashBank')}
       >
       <View style={styles.inner}>
         <Text style={styles.titleText}>CASH BANK</Text>
       </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

and I import MenuHome on Home Component.

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <MenuHome />
    </View>
  )
}
```

and i've been create CashBank Component, but i get `error Undefined is not object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MenuHome component takes the navigation as prop so you have to pass the navigation object to it

```
const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
      return (
        <View>
          <MenuHome navigation={navigation} />
        </View>
      )
    }
```

Another solution would be to use the hook provided by the library in your MenuHome component

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
const MenuHome = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.box}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('CashBank')}
       >
       <View style={styles.inner}>
         <Text style={styles.titleText}>CASH BANK</Text>
       </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```